# Post to facebook page as user using RestFB

Tags: java, facebook

I am able to post to a page wall as page admin. But I need to post to the page as a follower(page fan/ user). I am using RestFB api.

I am working with Facebook RestFB. I have a facebook page. The following code posts the message as page.

```
 FacebookType postResponse = fbPageClient.publish(Constants.PAGE_ID + "/feed", FacebookType.class, Parameter.with("message", fbmessage));
```

But I want to post to the page as a user who is following the page. Is it to possible? If so, what should I do?

Can someone help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add more details

Comment: I am working with Facebook RestFB. I have a facebook page. The following code posts the message as page.
       
        FacebookType postResponse 
= fbPageClient.publish(Constants.PAGE_ID + "/feed", FacebookType.class, Parameter.with("message", fbmessage));

But I want to post to the page as a user who is following the page. Is it to possible? If so, what should I do?

Comment: Use a user access token from the user you want to post as

Comment: I have tried that too.
FacebookType response = fbclient.publish(Constants.PAGE_ID + "/feed", FacebookType.class, Parameter.with("message", message));
fbClient is created with the user access token I acquired during login. It throws the following error.
com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: Invalid OAuth access token. (code 190, subcode null)

Comment: Then it is a not a valid user access token

Comment: I have debugged the access token in Facebook Access token debugger. I shows the correct details.
'Valid  True'